# Multiple inverse relationships in Core Data

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an entity Library that mains two lists of Books.  It is important that the library maintain these two lists of books.  On my Library entity I have a relationship thats one to many from each list to my Book entity.  Likewise, Book has a relationship "library".  I'm having some problems with my data being erased from the database and I read that I should be setting up inverse relationships to help with data integrity.  In this case however, a Book would want to be able to set up an inverse relationship with each list on my Library entity.  How can I accomplish this?

My naive first thought is to implement relationships for both lists.  So a book has a relationship "libraryForList1" and "libraryForList2" so that it can have an inverse for each relationship.  I'll never have to actually reference these properties because according to the Core Data spec, if I add a book to one of the library lists, it automatically takes care of setting the library as that books owner.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985075/core-data-inverse-relationship-for-two-relationships-with-same-type/4989413 , among others. If your library can own books in two different ways, then a book can belong to a library in two different ways, and both need to be modeled separately.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your "naive first thought" is essentially correct: If your Library entity has two one-to-many relationships with Books (for clarity let's call the relationships `ownedBooks` and `borrowedBooks`), then your Book entity should have to-one inverse relationships (`owningLibrary` and `borrowingLibrary`) and then Core Data will make your life easier.

You may also need to think about the delete rules on these relationships: If a Book is deleted for some reason, the delete rules for the `owningLibrary` and `borrowingLibrary` would likely be *Nullify* – that is, both libraries would remove the Book from their lists. Deleting a Library that still has Books seems like a bad idea, so maybe the delete rule for `ownedBooks` and `borrowedBooks` should be *Deny:* A Library can't be deleted until the books are all accounted for (and removed from the Library).