# Core Data setting inverse relationship for multiple similar child objects?

Tags: core-data

I'm running into an issue with my core data model. I would like to have an entity called TherapySession have two Mood events - start and end. To do so I've defined two relationships to child objects:

[image]

However, I would also like to create an inverse relationship, where each Mood object would be aware of it's parent therapy session. **I'm not sure how to properly create the inverse relationship between the child and parent object when there are more than one relationship of the same type defined.** In my case, the inverse relationship points to the "startMood" property of the therapy session:

[image]

It seems that I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot put my finger on how to resolve this problem. If I add an end mood to therapy, and the core data would try to create an inverse relationship, would it overwrite the startMood relationship?

Thank you for any clarifications! I know that this can be avoided by adding a set of objects, and then sorting the set by date, but I would like to avoid having to do that for every object.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985075/core-data-inverse-relationship-for-two-relationships-with-same-type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution is to stick with a simple many-to-one relationship `mood` and an additional attribute in entity `Mood` that indicates start or end.

This is also more flexible - in the future it would be trivial to introduce more moods at different therapy points etc. without having to change the data model.

Comment: I like that idea. Would be easy to query, too.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I was afraid I would have to write more complicated queries when it's time to present data to the user with history or report.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if this is the right way to do this, but I always end up creating two inverse relationships, like `startMoodInverse` and `endMoodInverse`. (You can then add a property in code that returns whichever of those is non-nil as `therapySession`.)

Comment: Yes, it is the right way, so long as you're dealing with one-to-one relationships. Those need to be unique on both sides for inverse relationships to work.