# Saving various core data entities of the same type with multiple different relationships?

Tags: core-data

I've been trying to debug this for 2 hours, have to sleep. First, I've searched and found many similar posts with they keywords: many entities same type and this one:
[Core Data: inverse relationship for two relationships with same type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4985075/core-data-inverse-relationship-for-two-relationships-with-same-type)

But to no avail. Here's what's happening:
I have a data model with two types. For example, I have a Person, and that person can have 4 lists of emails. The email type is its own thing, so I make the person store 4 distinct sets (relationships) to each list.

Basically, when I retrieve one set, it grabs all of them. All 4 lists are now 1, and it doesn't seem to matter how I set the inverses. Actually these changes somehow caused the entire thing to not save anything, all nil objects when downloaded. Previous to this, it worked fine (except for shoving all 4 lists into one set). All I updated was the data model for relationships. I may have exported the files in the wrong order, but do not know if that's related.

I simply can't find the keyword combination to find if someone's asked this before. I don't see how it wouldn't come up, what I'm doing is basic abstraction. I keep thinking I overlooked one box.

To summarize, I have a person, and person has 2 lists. I add them similar to this:
person.friendEmailsList = downloadedEmailsFromFriends;
person.businessEmailsList = downloadedBusinessEmails;

so later, I access person.friendEmailsList (using the correct core data call, of course), and instead of getting just friends, I get everything... friends, businesses everything

Any suggestions would be appreciated

Comment: It turns out, it was a checkbox. Don't set the "parent"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible solutions.

First, you can use the approach you use. Just make sure that you also have corresponding reverse relationships from the other entity. So if you have 2 relationships to the same entity, that entity needs 2 distinct relationships back. E.g.

```
Person.friendsLists --->> List
Person.businessLists --->> List

List.friendPerson ---> Person
List.businessPerson ---> Person
```

The more flexible approach would be to have the list have an extra attribute `type` (could be a number as some kind of `enum`).

```
typedef enum {Friend = 1, Business } ListType;
```

You could put this into your `List.h` file. Now, to access just friend lists you can do this:

```
NSSet *friendList = [person.lists filteredSetUsingPredicate:
       [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type = %@", @(Friend)]];
```

This might be a bit much to type, so you can simplify by putting an accessor method into your Person.m (declare it in .h):

```
-(NSSet*)friendsLists {
    return [person.lists filteredSetUsingPredicate:
       [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"type = %@", @(Friend)]];
}
```

Now you can access the lists with the usual convenient `person.friendsLists`.

Comment: Ah, so separate inverses was the right way. Somehow it fudged the structure, but that's probably from my carelessness. I was thinking of the enumerated attribute also, following SQL style keys. If I can't manage the db, I'll use that method. I'll accept your answer once I get back, can't test it for a bit. Thanks a lot, it seems it was user-error on my behalf

Comment: It's creating subclasses when using the method of unique inverses, instead of just creating unique entities. It seems I may have to do the fetched attribute method. My coworker is suggesting 5 separate classes, each with no unique types, just to split core data. The fact this isn't working is bugging me though, SQL can separate this, but core data is shoving it into one table regardless. I don't think Apple would make that big of a flaw, keep thinking I'm doing it wrong. We ended up with 4x the original type using separate inverses because of that flaw

Comment: That's why I pointed out that this is not the best way conceptionally. The trouble is not Apple but the old-fashioned relational-database thinking instead of embracing the object graph.

Comment: Ah, alright. I'm up for using the object graph, but would that entail creating separate types? Or the enumerated method? I realize this is probably a basic in some book/guide and am totally willing to be pointed to somewhere that will explain how to do this the Core Data way. The only stuff I see in the core data guide says to define the inverses.

Comment: Go with my suggested additional attribute. It simplifies things enormously and represents a model much closer to "reality", i.e. the same types of things are just defined once.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking about what I'd do with an SQL table, and asked "would I make 2 tables of the same type, or use a foreign key in one", thus the attribute. The attribute also lets me define an abstract type to allow more different types of a similar nature to be included, just by updating one line in the data model. Thanks for your help! I just assumed Core Data might under-the-hood keep track of this, since they do a lot of similar stuff. Accepted